# javascript if conditional statement based on 3 values

Tags: javascript

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){

            if (track.pause) (track1.pause) (track2.pause)

 else if
    (track.play) 
        track.pause();
```

etc

I want the "track" to only play when all the tracks are pause, but it still plays while another track is onplay.

waiting for response please.

Comment: your logic is if track paused, do nothing. but if track play, pause it.

Answer (score 3):

You need [logical (boolean) operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
if( track.pause && track1.pause && track2.pause )
   //...
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you need it's use [boolean operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp):

```
 if (track.pause && track1.pause && track2.pause){
      // Do what you want when all paused
  } else if(track.play) {
    track.pause();     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use logical and operator(&&) as below

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){

     if (track.pause && track1.pause && track2.pause){
           // code here
     } else if(track.play){
              track.pause();
     }
}
```

Comment: because you have posted an unnecessary answer. there are already 2 answers explaining it

Comment: I didn't see 2nd answer while I was posting answer and 1st answer was good for developers but guy who is asking question doesn't seem to even know syntax so I posted 2nd answer. By the way thanks for vote back

Comment: "was good for developers" we shouldn't have to dumb down answers because people don't read the documentation.